# Why are these logical statements not deemed to be equivalent?

Tags: logic, self-learning

I'm working through a book on my own which has just introduced the ideas of $A \Rightarrow B, B \Leftarrow A$ and $A \Leftrightarrow B$.  It then gave 20 exercise questions to answer.  I've correctly answered all of them except for two, and I don't understand why my answers are incorrect.  The two questions are as follows:

Insert the symbol $ \Rightarrow $, $ \Leftarrow $ or $ \Leftrightarrow $ which fully represents the link between the two statements.

Question 1:

Statement A: $\frac{x}{x + 1} = 0$

Statement B: $x = 0$

My answer: $A \Leftrightarrow B$

Book's answer: $A \Rightarrow B$

For this one, it seems simple enough to see that $A \Rightarrow B$, but I don't understand why $A \Leftarrow B$ is false.  It seems no different to expressing $x = 0$ as something like $x + 1 - 1 = 0$.  Wouldn't $x = 0$ imply $x + 1 - 1 = 0$?

Question 2:

Statement A: $(a, b)$ is a point on the line $y = 2x-1$

Statement B: $b = 2a - 1$

My answer: $A \Leftrightarrow B$

Book's answer: $A \Rightarrow B$

Similar situation with this one.  If $(a, b)$ is a point on the line $y = 2x - 1$, that should imply $b = 2a - 1$.  Then surely, if $b = 2a - 1$, $(a, b)$ is going to be a point on the line $y = 2x - 1$.  So, again, I don't understand why $A \Leftarrow B$ is false.

Is my logic flawed?

Comment: I agree with you. The book seems to be wrong. About these answers, at least.

Comment: @ajotatxe Thanks for the comment.  I'm inclined to agree, but I'd like some more feedback as the answer below has left me uncertain.

Comment: For people happening upon this many years later, the book and the answer given below should both be thrown in the trash. Apparently, the equation $\frac 0{0+1}=0$ is failing for them.

Comment: @TedShifrin It is now in the trash.